# i want the line under EditText to stay put

Tags: android, colors, background, android-edittext

When typing in an edit text that blue line comes up under it. i want it to stay there w
even when not tying. This is because i have a dark background and your cant see that there is an input field there. If anyone has an other idea on how to see the EditText input please advise. 
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The drawable you are looking for is named `textfield_multiline_activated_holo_dark.9.png` and can be found in `...\android-sdk\platforms\android-**\data\res\drawable-*dpi`. Copy all of them to your project and then add the following to your `EditText` in your xml layout file:

```
android:background="@drawable/textfield_multiline_activated_holo_dark"
```

And, if necessary, change the text color there like this:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: Thanks,easy to implement.Many of us don't know such things.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a selections xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable">
</selector>
```

then make a styles.xml file and insert this:

```
<style name="EditTextLight" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">white</item>
</style>
```

And then style your edittext like this:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/EditTextHololight" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your styles.xml and simply put the following

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/YourChoice </item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file whatever.xml, add this to your root

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">
   .
   .
   <EditText... />
</LinearLayout>
```

The bottom should have changed depending on the color that you set